# ¿Cómo paso de una vista a otra en Swift XCode?

Tags: firebase, ios, xcode, programación-móvil, swift4

Estoy haciendo un **login** con FireBase, es mi inicio con Swift y quiero pasar de una vista a otra cuando el usuario haga login.

Creo que el problema está en que no se utilizar los `segues`

Está es mi función:

```
func loginUser(){
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userTxt.text!, password: contraTxt.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if(user != nil){
                let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
                print("Logueado"+user!)
                *self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goMain", sender: SecondViewController.self)*

            }else{
                print("Error loguin")
            }

        })
    }
```

[image: Mi StoryBoard]

Answer (score 2):

La función está hecha perfectamente, el problema radicaba en donde habia creado la segue, tenia que enlazarla no en la action del button sino desde el activity

[image: Asi se pone la segue]

```
func loginUser(){
        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: userTxt.text!, password: contraTxt.text!, completion: { (user, error) in
            if(user != nil){
                let user = Auth.auth().currentUser?.email
                print("Logueado"+user!)
                self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goMain", sender: SecondViewController.self)

            }else{
                print("Error loguin")
            }

        })
    }
```